# Set screensavers used in Random Mode

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver

When setting screensavers options in Ubuntu, my only choices are :
- to leave the screen blank
- to select a specific screensaver
- or to ask Ubuntu to change screensavers at random

I seem to recall being able to select which screensavers I wanted to appear in the random rotation, but on the latest Ubuntu, that option seems to have disappeared.

How can I choose which screensavers I want in the random mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable that feature you need to install xscreensaver.

Here is how you can replace gnome-screensaver with xscreensaver:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=195557

Comment: That link is from 2006. Have the commands changed ?

Answer (score 1):

use [xscreensaver](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/intrepid/+package/xscreensaver) with Random Same Saver

> ***This option only appears if you have multiple monitors.***
>                           This is just like Random Screen Saver, except that  the
>                           same  randomly-chosen  display  mode will be run on all
>                           monitors, instead of a different one being run on each.